# Get matched Blacklist words that appears in a provided string

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, asp.net-4.5

I have an array containing a list of blacklist words as strings. This function returns true if at least one word from the blacklist appears in the text.

```
 private static bool IsSuspectedAsSpam(string text, IEnumerable<string> wordBlacklist)
    {
        string temp = text.ToLower();
        return wordBlacklist.Any(s => temp.Contains(s));           
    }
```

How can I get the words from the black list that where found in the text, as I want to print them on the web page.

Comment: Considered Any -> Where?

Comment: to get the words you have 2 choices, 1 change the return to have the list of words but then you loose the boolean and have to check if count > 0. Second add a reference parameter to be the words found.

Comment: @Andrei inside a loop and print it out?

Comment: `var matches = wordBlacklist.Where(word => temp.Contains(word));`

Comment: @IdanShechter, why loop? That plus ToList will give you a list of all blacklist words that occur in text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `Where` instead of `Any`:

```
private static IEnumerable<string> GetSpamWords(string text, IEnumerable<string> wordBlacklist)
{
    return wordBlacklist.Where(s => text.ToLower().Contains(s)).ToList();
}
```

This will return the list of strings which were matched in your text.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Where](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of Any

```
private static List<string> GetSpamWords(string text, IEnumerable<string> wordBlacklist)
{
            string temp = text.ToLower();
            return wordBlacklist.Where(s => temp.Contains(s)).ToList();           
}
```